# Grouping entries and ordering by section

Tags: templating, filter, ordering, group

Im grabbing entries from two sections and displaying them using the group filter.

```
{% set entries = craft.entries().section('extendedEvents, festivalEvents')%}
{% set allEvents = entries %}
{% set allEventsBySection = allEvents|group('section') %}

{% for section, eventsInSection in allEventsBySection %}
- results- 
{% endfor %}
```

No matter what I do the results are coming back ordered as section2 (entry, entry, entry) then section 1 (entry, entry, entry)

How do I affect the order of the sections when displaying the results?

Comment: Not sure if I got it wrong but what is your goal exactly? Ordering by `orderBy({sectionId: SORT_ASC})` in your main Query?

Comment: Thanks, that worked - as there were only two sections I just reversed the arrays in the for loop which also did the job

Comment: @Kevin Can you add your solution as an official answer? Might end up helping someone in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The suggestion to order by sectionId resolved my issue here.

{% set entries = craft.entries().section('extendedEvents, festivalEvents'). orderBy({sectionId: SORT_ASC}) %}

As it was, I was working with two sections, so my quick fix was to simply reverse the order of the output of the for loop...

{% for section, eventsInSection in allEventsBySection | reverse %}